# DiDom - file_get_contents, HTTP Request generates Error: 404 Not Found

Tags: php

I'm using the [didom](https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM) library on localhost. What can be the solution to this error when I get an error when it comes to a url that has a 404 page?

```
    use DiDom\Document;
    $dr = new Document($product->dr, true);
    $drcom = $dr->first('.product-price')->xpath('//p')[0]->text();

    echo $drcom;
```

Error Result

```
Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(https://www.dr.com.tr/Kitap/Kordugum/Edebiyat/Roman/Dunya-Roman/urunno=000000054584545445): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Filename: DiDom/Document.php

Line Number: 372

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\imangazaliev\didom\src\DiDom\Document.php
Line: 372
Function: file_get_contents
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit, changed the code to @file_get_contents. And now he's making a mistake like that.

```
Type: RuntimeException

Message: Could not load file https://www.dr.com.tr/Kitap/Kordugum/Edebiyat/Roman/Dunya-Roman/urunno=000000054584545445

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\imangazaliev\didom\src\DiDom\Document.php

Line Number: 378

Backtrace:
```